# The rendered image looks clipped, but in the viewport the clip distance seems OK

Tags: rendering, camera

I am rendering a scene, and the plane in the scene is being clipped for no apparent reason.  The near and far clip of the camera seems ok, but I extended it to 300 from 100, just in case, and no dice.

The following two images shows how it looks in blender, and the render result:

[image: Blender workspace]

[image]

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2NUT.jpg)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2NUT.jpg):

EDIT: Links to blend file added
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44179449/jeemoneygrungebrickangled.blend

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44179449/jeemoneygrungebrickangled.blend1

EDIT 2:

I moved the camera back away from the plane, and this is WEIRD!  Why is it not a rectangular plane?  (Note: I moved the JeeMoney text over, so that didn't automatically change position because of the new camera distance)

[image]

EDIT 3: 
After 2 hours of fiddling around, I found out that I had a subsurf & displacement modifer that was messing everything up.  I fixed it.  Thanks all!

Comment: sub-surf modifier?

Comment: Please post your blend file so we can take a look at it more closely.

Comment: I added the blend files via dropbox.

Comment: I mean, I put the links above in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Clipping Distance settings exist in two places.

One set for the viewport (in your Properties Panel):

[image: Viewport clip settings]

...and another for the Camera / rendering:

[image: Camera clip settings]

Edit:

## However...

Now that you've posted your .blend and I've had a chance to examine it, I can say your issue has nothing to do with clipping distance.

You have a SubSurf Modifier on your plane that is curving it.

[image: SubSurf on Plane]

It was set only to be visible in renders, not in the viewport.

Edit again:

I just saw your comment that you fixed it, so never mind. One last thing I'll mention - you can leave the SubSurf Modifier on, but switch it to **Simple** instead of **Catmull-Clark**, and this will give you the fine geometry for the Displace Modifier that follows, without rounding your plane.

Comment: Both nears are set to .1 which should be enough.  I changed the end to be set to 2000 in the former, and 500 in the latter.  Still get the same behavior.

Comment: Depending on the units you're using, the difference between the camera at 100 clip and 500 clip could be insignificant. Set the camera end clip to 10000.

Comment: Mentalist, thank you for looking into it!  I appreciate your time!  That was the solution!